# Lost connection to MySQL server during query - is table size a problem?

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I'm using HeidiSQL as a tool for querying data. Until yesterday I had no problems with connecting to my database. Since today I can't retrieve the data from 1 table. All other tables are fine. The table that's causing the "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" error is the biggest though, 2GiB (plus the size bar is full but still green).

I've tried changing the settings for net_read_timeout, net_retry_count and net_write_timeout but this doesn't solve it.

Can anyone help me out as to where I should be looking to solve this? At first I thought it may be the table size but now I'm not so sure.

Comment: Most likely you are running some wierd (possibly a `CROSS JOIN`) query which needs to go through a mass number of records and the MySQL server protects it self from a "DDoS" by killing the process and connection.. Show the query and the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` for every table involved in your table.  Also post a `EXPLAIN query` then we can help.

Comment: The query doesn't contain any joins or anything extensive. Even a simple select all from table gives the error. There's just one table involved.

Comment: I would check the time out for the following elements:

- Client timeout connection
- Server timeout connection
- Max time execution (timeout for query running)

Comment: Still share some table structures, the queries you use and the explains off those queries we can't help you like this..

Comment: Well I don't know what you mean by the explains..?
What do you want to know about table structures? It's just a table with columns and rows. An example query is just SELECT * FROM table.
@Miguel I can't find those in my variables in HeidiSQL, where should I find those?

Comment: Have you tried to LIMIT the query to see if you get any results?

Comment: Yes, a limit doesn't solve the problem either (tried limits 10, 100 and 1000).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, the SQL DB timed out because it was called upon too much (by the DBwriter and users).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem. Basically my table was called upon multiple times until it didn;t respond. I had to kill all the processes that were calling the table.

[Kill Proccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azTAz.png)